# Integers whose multiples contain a specific digit

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

In base 10 (or any other base, for that matter) is there an integer all whose multiples contain a specific digit, say 1?

Comment: Every integer has a multiple entirely comprised of digits $0$ and $9$.

Comment: All multiples of $0, 10$ or $210$ will contain the digit $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In base $b$, we can represent a number $n$ as $xy$ with $\gcd(x,b)=1$ and $y|b^k$ for some $k$. Let $z=b^k/y$, so $xb$ is a multiple of $n$. Then, if we consider

$$b^k\left(b^{\varphi(x)}-1\right),$$

it is a multiple of $x$ by Euler's theorem, and only contains the "digits" $0$ and $b-1$. Similarly,

$$b^k\left(\frac{b^{(b-1)\varphi(x)}-1}{b-1}\right)$$

is a multiple of $n$ and has only the digits $1$ and $0$. So, the only digit that could necessarily exist in every multiple of $n$ is $0$, and if $b|n$ then every multiple of $n$ has a $0$.

Note: this only works in bases $b>2$. If $b=2$, then every nonzero number has a one.

Comment: So the question comes up, does there exist a number where $b \not \mid n$ but in which a $0$ must always pop up somewhere in the middle and we can never "squeeze" the $0$s out?

Comment: @fleablood my instinct says that one should be able to make what is essentially a string of $(b-1)$s and then multiply it by a suitable factor of $b^k$, but I don't know how the details would shake out.

Comment: Yeah.  My instincts say so too but... I don't want to have to shake the details out.

Comment: The question then arises: for each n what is the least integer in base 10 (base b) whose first n multiples contain the digit d<10 (d<b)?